# URL Naming practise

Tags: seo, url, ranking, clean-urls

Hi wanted to check if at the end of the URL (`http://www.abcd.com/product-name/subproduct,default,sc.html`) we have characters like `default,sc` and then `.html`, does having `default,sc` have an impact on search ranking as the URL is not clean....

Thoughts / views would be great help

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Having short clean URLs can help a very small amount with SEO.  That is because users tend to click on them more when they are displayed in the SERPs.  The more complicated the URL the fewer people click.  The magnitude of this effect is small enough that it isn't worth worrying about if there is a technical reason that your URLs need to end like that.

Your use of commas in the URL is more worrying to me from an SEO standpoint.  According to http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm: URLs use commas for a special use in defining their syntax. When a commas is not used in its special role inside a URL, it needs to be encoded.  I would try to use a hyphen separator instead of a comma.

Comment: Agree, You should replace those commas with good old hyphens.